# Discord.py random choice bug

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Code:

```
# Random Choice
@client.command(aliases=["rand_c"])
async def random_choice(ctx, python_list):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(python_list))
```

Weird error when I type a proper Python list (["Cats", "Dogs", "No pet"]):

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.UnexpectedQuoteError: Unexpected quote mark, '"', in non-quoted string
```

It works fine in regular Python, but why not in discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the inputs to your commands are initially treated as strings.  You need to provide a converter function to tell the command what to do with that string:

```
from ast import literal_eval

@client.command(aliases=["rand_c"])
async def random_choice(ctx, *, python_list: literal_eval):
    await ctx.send(str(python_list))
```